# Do git hooks push and pull?

Tags: git, githooks

If I have a local repository pulled from a remote one, and I add [git hooks](http://githooks.com/) to my local repository before I push it back to the remote one, do the hooks go to the remote repo with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Nothing that you add directly under the `.git` directory will be sent from clone to clone, including hooks. It's a little inconvenient sometimes, but it also means that you can easily have different hooks in different clones, so it's a tradeoff.

One strategy is to put your hook scripts in a directory that *is* tracked by git, and write a script that symlinks them in to `.git`, so developers can easily wire them up in a fresh clone.